# How to deal with multiple when condition for registered variable in ansible

Tags: variables, error-handling, ansible, case

I have a playbook 3 raw task (or more) with sample commands like below:

Playbook `mytest.yml`

```yaml
- hosts: remotehost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Execute command1
      raw: "ls -ltr"
      register: cmdoutput
      when: remcmd == "list"

    - name: Execute command2
      raw: "hostname"
      register: cmdoutput
      when: remcmd == "host"

    - name: Execute command3
      raw: "uptime"
      register: cmdoutput
      when: remcmd == "up"

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Printing {{ hostvars['remotehost']['cmdoutput'] }}"
```

This is my nventory `myhost.yml`

```ini
[remotehost]
myserver1
```

Here is how I run the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i myhost.yml mytest.yml -e remcmd="host"

PLAY [remotehost] ***************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Execute command1] *********************************************************************************************************
Thursday 06 October 2022  07:06:06 -0500 (0:00:00.013)       0:00:00.013 ******
skipping: [myserver1]

TASK [Execute command2] *********************************************************************************************************
Thursday 06 October 2022  07:06:06 -0500 (0:00:00.023)       0:00:00.036 ******
changed: [myserver1]

TASK [Execute command3] *********************************************************************************************************
Thursday 06 October 2022  07:06:06 -0500 (0:00:00.521)       0:00:00.557 ******
skipping: [myserver1]

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 06 October 2022  07:06:06 -0500 (0:00:00.032)       0:00:00.590 ******
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['remotehost']\" is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/wladmin/mytest.yml': line 22, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
myserver1                : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

My requirement is no matter what value is passed for `remcmd` my localhost play should print `stdoutlines` of `cmdoutput`

Comment: Please note that your inventory is named with a `.yml` extension and contains an ini style inventory. Fortunately, ansible handles this quite smoothly by trying inventory plugins in order until one matches but that might break one day.

Answer (score 2):

Preliminary notes:

1. **Using raw is evil**.
2. Don't use raw unless to install prereqs (i.e. python) on the target host. Then switch to modules or at the very least command/shell
3. If you still intend to use raw, go back to point 1 above
4. In case your forgot to go back to point 1: **using raw is evil**

---

Don't register several tasks with the same var name (the last one always win, even if skipped). Don't create tasks you can avoid up-start.

As an illustration of the above principles

```yaml
- hosts: remotehost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    cmd_map:
      list: ls -ltr
      host: hostname
      up: uptime
  
  tasks:
    - name: Make sure remcmd is known
      assert:
        that: remcmd in cmp_map.keys()
        fail_msg: "remcmd must be one of: {{ cmd_map.keys() | join(', ') }}"

    - name: Execute command
      command: "{{ cmd_map[remcmd] }}"
      register: cmdoutput

    - name: Show entire result from above task
      debug:
        var: cmdoutput
```

Comment: "_Don't register several tasks with the same var name (the last one always win, even if skipped). Don't create tasks you can avoid up-start._" these are indeed very good points to consider during writing a playbook, to take in and to prevent "spaghetti code". Your given example is much more clear and clean.

Answer (score 1):

> *my localhost play should print `stdout_lines` of `cmdoutput`*

As far as I understand "How the debug module works", it can only print on the Control Node.

Therefore you could just remove three (3) lines in your example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
```

and give it a try with

```yaml
- hosts: remotehost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - name: Execute command1
      raw: "ls -ltr"
      register: cmdoutput
      when: remcmd == "list"

    - name: Execute command2
      raw: "hostname"
      register: cmdoutput
      when: remcmd == "host"

    - name: Execute command3
      raw: "uptime"
      register: cmdoutput
      when: remcmd == "up"

    - debug:
        msg: "Printing {{ cmdoutput }}"
```

and independently of which task became executed the result would be provided.

Apart from the answer about "How the debug module works" here, I like to recommended to [proceed further with the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974044/6771046) of Zeitounator, since it will address your possible use case more complete.

Comment: @Zeitounator i will test this by tomorrow and update